# How to customize bibliography in latex

Tags: biblatex, texworks

I have latex document and bibliography in it.

main.tex has following commands in preamble:

- `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}`
- `\addbibresource{example.bib}`

`example.bib` contains following content:

```latex
@article{tmp,
    Author = {John Smith},
    Journal = {TmpJournal},
    Title = {TmpTitle},
    Year = {2014}}
```

In the pdf document it looks like this:

[image]

The point is I don't want this part: "In" (from "...In: TmpJournal(2014)")

**I want to be able to change "In" to different word**

How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which word, if you don't mind?

Comment: @Bernard Hi, I mean the word "In", from the "TmpTitle. In: TmpJournal(2014)", I want to change it to different word

Comment: I had understood this, but which word do you want?

Comment: @Bernard I want to change it into "W", because its supposed to be written in polish language

Comment: But if you load babel with option `polish`, this should be automatic. Unless you want it only for some references, because their language is polish?

Comment: I can actually confirm that using `\usepackage[polish]{babel}` does exactly that.

Comment: @Bernard Than you, I didn't know that latex has support for polish language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full code example using the `babel` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
    @article{tmp,
        Author = {John Smith},
        Journal = {TmpJournal},
        Title = {TmpTitle},
        Year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In case you do not want to use `polish` as your main document language, you could either use additional languages, such as `\usepackage[polish,main=english]{babel}`.

The alternative would be redefining the `bibmacro` that places the `In:` but that seems a little over the top at this point.